# grub2-mkconfig not working

Tags: linux, grub2

I've updated the /etc/grub.d/40_custom for a custom menu entry as follows:

```
menuentry "My OS"{
   rootnoverify (hd1,0)
   chainloader +1
}
```

I run this command:

```
grub2-mkconfig –o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

It displays the output:

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.

menuentry "My OS"{
    rootnoverify (hd1,0)
    chainloader +1
}
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
```

And it does nothing after. Can you let me know what else I need to do? Thanks.

Comment: I tried removing the custom entry (from 40_custom) and removed grub.cfg. Running grub2-mkconfig –o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg still does nothing.

Comment: Messed up grub by renaming the grub config file. Entered recue mode using Centos recovery disk and all the commands work: grub2-mkconfig generates the config file and grub2-install updates grub. Really odd!